# Why can't I make a TimeSeriesForecast with a GARCH model?

Tags: time-series

I am playing with `TimeSeriesForecast` and I find that it invariably forecasts 0 for `GARCH` models. It is possible that I am misunderstanding `TimeSeriesForecast`, or that I am misunderstanding GARCH models and I would appreciate any guidance.

Take as an example,

```
data = {5., 9., 8., 10., 6.1, 10.4, 9.1, 11.6, 7.5, 12.1, 10.4, 13.5, 
   9., 14.1, 11.9, 15.7, 10.8, 16.4, 13.7, 18.3, 12.9, 19., 15.8, 21.2,
   15.3, 22.1, 18.3, 24.6, 20, 20, 31, 31, 42, 42, 55, 55, 43, 22, 11,
    233, 432, 12, 23, 34, 23};
```

`TimeSeriesModelFit` and `TimeSeriesForecast` work for `ARMA` and other model types. For example,

```
In[]:= tsArima = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, "ARIMA"];
In[]:= TimeSeriesForecast[tsArima, 10]
Out[]= 33.2511 (* ok, works *)

In[]:= tsGarch = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, {"GARCH", {1, 1}}];
In[]:= TimeSeriesForecast[tsGarch , 10]
Out[]= 0 (* always *)
```

It doesn't matter what the source data is, GARCH always returns `0` and never produces an error. What am I missing here?

Comment: I note that there is an example in the GARCHProcess documentation that precisely does this, and where the author does not seem to be surprised at all. Perhaps something related to a property of this random process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TimeSeriesForecast` returns the conditional expectation which for GARCH process is always zero. Therefore you always get 0. Now `TimeSeriesForecast[tsGarch, 10]` returns a forecasted value ONLY, hence you get 0. If you want to get the forecast WITH the errors, you need to call `TimeSeriesForecast` with a list of steps so it does return `TemporalData` that carries the error information:

```
In[8]:= data = {5., 9., 8., 10., 6.1, 10.4, 9.1, 11.6, 7.5, 12.1, 
   10.4, 13.5, 9., 14.1, 11.9, 15.7, 10.8, 16.4, 13.7, 18.3, 12.9, 
   19., 15.8, 21.2, 15.3, 22.1, 18.3, 24.6, 20, 20, 31, 31, 42, 42, 
   55, 55, 43, 22, 11, 233, 432, 12, 23, 34, 23};

In[21]:= tsGarch = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, {"GARCH", {1, 1}}];
forecast = TimeSeriesForecast[tsGarch, {1}];
forecast // Head

Out[23]= TemporalData

In[24]:= forecast["Path"]

Out[24]= {{45, 0}}

In[25]:= forecast["Properties"]

Out[25]= {"Components", "DateList", "DatePath", "DatePaths", "Dates", \
"FirstDates", "FirstTimes", "FirstValues", "LastDates", "LastTimes", \
"LastValues", "MeanSquaredErrors", "Part", "Path", "PathCount", \
"PathFunction", "PathFunctions", "PathLength", "PathLengths", \
"Paths", "PathTimes", "SliceData", "SliceDistribution", "TimeList", \
"Times", "ValueDimensions", "ValueList", "Values"}

In[26]:= errors = forecast["MeanSquaredErrors"];

In[27]:= errors // Head

Out[27]= TemporalData

In[28]:= errors["Path"]

Out[28]= {{45, 4590.48}}
```

And yes, this is all documented - see last example in Scope/BasicUses on GARCHProcess reference page :)